# what is the difference between * and Object

Tags: actionscript-3

Let's say I have a class with some a couple properties:

```
public class MyClass {
   public var fooProp:*;
   public var barProp:Object;
}
```

What is the difference, practically speaking, between these? Are there variable types I can later assign to fooProp that I cannot assign to barProp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only untyped variables can hold the value `undefined`.  Untyped variables are variables that either lack any type annotation, or use the asterisk `*` symbol for type annotation.

[From ActionScript data type descriptors](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_11.html):

> In previous versions of ActionScript, a variable with no type
>   annotation was automatically assigned the Object data type. This is no
>   longer true in ActionScript 3.0, which now includes the idea of a
>   truly untyped variable. Variables with no type annotation are now
>   considered untyped. If you prefer to make it clear to readers of your
>   code that your intention is to leave a variable untyped, you can use
>   the new asterisk (*) symbol for the type annotation, which is
>   equivalent to omitting a type annotation. The following example shows
>   two equivalent statements, both of which declare an untyped variable:
>
> ```
> var x 
> var x:*
> ```
>
> Only untyped variables can hold the value undefined. If you attempt to
>   assign the value undefined to a variable that has a data type, Flash
>   Player or Adobe AIR will convert the value undefined to the default
>   value of that data type. For instances of the Object data type, the
>   default value is null, which means that Flash Player or Adobe AIR will
>   convert the value undefined to null if you attempt to assign undefined
>   to an Object instance.

As an example:

```
var t:* = undefined;
trace(t); // outputs: undefined

var t:Object = undefined;
trace(t); // outputs: null
```